# JS to SQL datetime

Tags: .net, sql

I am passing from the client a date time that looks something like this...

"Mon Nov 05 2012 21:27:58 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"

I want to save this into a sql datetime field while retaining as much of the date data as possible.

At the moment I'm doing a conversion like this in the .net backend before I save the datetime to the database....

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, 24),
                             "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This loses the GMT part.

Is there a way that I can keep it in a ParseExact that will be suitable for SQL?